# How to prevent constant and variable values from resetting upon page refresh?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, frontend

enter code hereI am working on a web app similar to Wordle, but for songs. I have done up the onClick function and it's currently working for a single render, but I want the song/audio to only change **every 24 hours/a fixed time** instead of on every page refresh.

I'm wondering how Wordle does this? Do you require a backend API for it? I am currently building my app with Vite + Remix for frontend, and I have prepared a node/express API and a MongoDB db but I have not reached the stage of development for it to be used yet.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { songList } from "./song-list";

    export default function InputSection() {
      const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
      const audioStatus = useRef(false);
      const randomSongIndex = useRef(songList.length + 1);
      const startTimeRef = useRef(36000);
      const audioRef = useRef(null);
    
      const getRandomFromRange = (min: number, max: number): number => {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        randomSongIndex.current = getRandomFromRange(0, songList.length);
        const randomSong = songList[randomSongIndex.current];
        const audio = new Audio(randomSong);
        audioRef.current = audio;
        audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
          const startTime = getRandomFromRange(0, audio.duration - 6);
          startTimeRef.current = startTime;
        });
        return () => {
          audio.removeEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {});
        };
      }, []);
    
      const handlePlay = () => {
        if (audioStatus.current) {
          return;
        }
        audioStatus.current = true;
        const audio = audioRef.current;
        audio.currentTime = startTimeRef.current;
        audio.play();
    
        setTimeout(() => {
          audio.pause();
          audioStatus.current = false; // Reset the state when audio finishes playing
        }, 1000);
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <section className="flex flex-col items-center gap-4">
            <button onClick={handlePlay}>
              <img
                src="assets/play-button.svg"
                alt="Play"
              />
            </button>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search for song title"
              className="h-8 w-full bg-gray-300 p-2 border border-black"
            />
          </section>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Not sure if there are any react hooks or in built functions that support this as it's my first time building something of this scale.

Comment: This needs code for context.

Comment: @tadman added my code

Comment: The original wordle had a giant array of words and is indexed by day. For example, today is 19779 days since the start of 1970 (beginning of unix epoch) so if you have an array of 3653 words you can generate one word per day for 10 years from today by doing `word_array[Math.floor(Date.now()/1000/60/60/24) - 19779]`. Basically just an index into an array by days from today. That was how the original Wordle worked. The current Wordle gets its word from New York Time's servers

Comment: ... You may have noticed that if what I described above is true than the original Wordle didn't hide its word list at all and anyone looking at the source files can know today's word. Yes this is true and yes people knew about it but almost everyone who played it resisted looking at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a storage.

e.g. frontend side localStorage, cookies, indexed DB, ...
backend side: database.

When initializing the state you would check your storage and use the stored value or get a new one.